# How to use Oracle packages instead of using Oracle store Procedure in c# by Adapter(XSD)?

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql

As we able to retrieve the data through store Procedure from oracle to c#. Is there is any possibilities to use packages of oracle in C# to retrieve and handling data.

Comment: I'm not familiar with C# but if you're able to call a stand-alone PL/SQL subprogram then you should be able to call a package subroutine as well. Package is the way to modularize PL/SQL code. Read the fine manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/packages.htm

Comment: But there is no examples regarding c#...!!

Comment: Your question seems to indicate you don't understand the difference of Oracle PL/SQL standalone subroutines and packages. Reading the fine manual should clarify that point. Second you claim to be able already to call a standalone subroutine. Calling a package should be no different from C# point of view. The only difference is that calling package subroutines always requires package name, like `mypackage.mysubroutine`.